# SetState not Updating the Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Hello I was trying to create a Mpin menu using "pin_code_text_field: ^1.5.1" I have create a dart file for the pin_code_text_field plugin already and working now my next goal was to activate the button done if their are already 6 digits on the pin but when I am using setState on the variable the value is changing but the UI or button is not updating here is the code below. Can you suggest what have gone wrong and any best practice for this kind.

Inactive button when no pin or not complete
[image: Inactive button when no pin or not complete]

Active Button when pin is complete

[image: Active Button when pin is complete]

```
class _setMPin extends State<setMPin>{
TextEditingController initialPincontroller = TextEditingController(text: "");
bool initPinButtonInActive = true;
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    initPinButtonInActive = true;
    hasError = true;
  }


    void nextPinVerification(){
    print("done success");
    controller.clear();
  }
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget initialPin = Container(
      width: 400,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            child: new PinCodeTextField(
              autofocus: true,
              controller: initialPincontroller,
              hideCharacter: true,
              highlight: true,
              highlightColor: Colors.blue,
              defaultBorderColor: Colors.black,
              pinBoxWidth: 60,
              pinBoxHeight: 50,
              hasTextBorderColor: Colors.green,
              maxLength: pinLength,
              hasError: hasError,
              maskCharacter: "*",
              onTextChanged: (text) {
                setState(() {
                  hasError = false;
                  initPinButtonInActive = true;
                });
              },
              onDone: (text){
                print(text.length);
                if(text.length == 6){
                  setState(() {
                    print(text.length);
                    hasError = true;
                    initPinButtonInActive = false;
                  });
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Visibility(
            child: Text(
              'Incorrect Pin Format',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            ),
            visible: hasError,
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[ Expanded(
                child:Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5,top: 20),
                    child:  ButtonTheme(
                      minWidth: 190,
                      height: 50,
                      child: new FlatButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)
                        ),
                        child: new Text("Done",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        disabledColor: Colors.blue[200],
                        onPressed: initPinButtonInActive ? null : nextPinVerification
                      ),
                    )
                )
            )],
          )

        ],
      )
    );
        return WillPopScope(
        child: MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                initialPin,

              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
        onWillPop: (){
          Navigator.pop(context);
    return Future.value(false);
  }
        );

  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set following code

```
onTextChanged: (text) {
            setState(() {
              hasError = false;
              initPinButtonInActive = true;
              if(text.length== 6 ){
              hasError = true;
              initPinButtonInActive = false;
              }
            });
          },
```

And remove onDone part.

Comment: Thanks working now. Sir can you explain what is the issue so I know.

Comment: onDone is called when you remove pointer from text field but  ontextchanged is continues checking text field data.in your case you are using only one text field so pointer is stuck on that text field only so it cannot change the state.so use of ontextfieldchange  is better than onDone event.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to be doing is setting the text property or your controller in setState when onDone is called like this

```
 onDone: (text){
                print(text.length);
                if(text.length == 6){
                  setState(() {
                    print(text.length);
                    initialPincontroller.text = text;
                    hasError = true;
                    initPinButtonInActive = false;
                  });
                }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sir I want to button to be active when the pin is complete and inactive when its not